# Upstart respawning healthy process

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10, upstart

I'm having an issue where upstart is respawning a Node.js (v0.8.8) process that is completely healthy.  I'm on Ubunut 11.10.  When I run the program from the command line it is completely stable and does not crash.  But, when I run it with upstart, it gets respawned pretty consistently every few seconds.  I'm not sure what is going on and none of logs seem to help.  In fact, there are no error messages produced any of the upstart logs for the job.  Below is my upstart script:

```
#!upstart
description "server.js"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on shutdown

# Automtically respawn
respawn                 # restart when job dies
respawn limit 99 5      # give up restart after 99 respawns in 5 seconds

script
    export HOME="/home/www-data"

    exec sudo -u www-data NODE_ENV="production" /usr/local/bin/node /var/www/server/current/server.js >> /var/log/node.log 2>> /var/log/node.error.log
end script

post-start script
    echo "server-2 has started!"
end script
```

The strange thing is that server-1 works perfectly fine and is setup the same way.

syslog messages look like this:

Sep 24 15:40:28 domU-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx kernel: [5272182.027977] init: server-2 main process (3638) terminated with status 1

Sep 24 15:40:35 domU-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx kernel: [5272189.039308] init: server-2 main process (3647) terminated with status 1

Sep 24 15:40:42 domU-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx kernel: [5272196.050805] init: server-2 main process (3656) terminated with status 1

Sep 24 15:40:49 domU-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx kernel: [5272203.064022] init: server-2 main process (3665) terminated with status 1

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: thanks for posting your config. did you change it since 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems that it was actually monit that was restarting it.  Problem has been solved.  Thanks.